# If I moved my Xcode project folder to another computer running OS X, Can the app still be built and run there?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I have an Xcode project that needs to be copied to another Mac. Because I don't have another Mac, I can't try it to see what happens.

If the user opens the .xcodeproj file and build it. Will the build succeed? And if he/she opens the project and click on the run button on the top-left corner, will the app run on a simulator?

I am asking this because in project settings, I set the Team to myself, I'm afraid that the app won't run because of this. Because I think when you run the app, it finds the certificates from the keychain. If a valid certificate is found, the app will run. But in someone else's Mac, the keychain does not contain the required certificate. So I think the app might not run successfully.

Will the project run on other Macs if they don't have the certificates? Do I need to do additional things to make this work?

Comment: No It will work. some times my apps i run on my office mac. there is no issue. i have two different team sets in Generals. my one and office team one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, As long as you aren't trying to run it on a physical device and only the simulator it will work.

If you are trying to install and run it on a physical device you will need to be able to link your username/certificate type thing in the build settings in Xcode